# get a specific file at special commit url using git cli

Tags: git

Can I get the file url from git command line?

For example, In here, https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=history;f=src/test/regress/sql/alter_table.sql;hb=784cedda0604ee4ac731fd0b00cd8b27e78c02d3
I can see all the changes about file alter_table.sql.

If I choose the latest one, I will get `alter_table.sql` latest url **A**: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/test/regress/sql/alter_table.sql;h=e7013f5e154404526cd5b920104b77e19ae7dc65;hb=784cedda0604ee4ac731fd0b00cd8b27e78c02d3
But I already pull the code from git. In my local repo, is there any way I can get the specific file at special commit url.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+file+specific+commit

Comment: `git show 784cedda0604ee4ac731fd0b00cd8b27e78c02d3:src/test/regress/sql/alter_table.sql`